# VueJS Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wanted to use this third party [toast](https://github.com/Stabzs/vue-on-toast) component in my VueJS app but it is giving error,

```
Unknown custom element: <toast-container> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

**main.ts**

```
import VueOnToast from 'vue-on-toast';
..
Vue.use(BootstrapVue, Vuex, VueOnToast);
```

**App.vue**

```
<toast-container></toast-container>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the signature of [`Vue.use`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use):

```
Vue.use( plugin )
```

`Vue.use` only expects a single argument. If you pass more than that, they are ignored.

You have to use it like this:

```
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueOnToast);
```